# Update same object twice in after insert and after update trigger

Tags: salesforce

if i try to insert records my after update trigger is running and when aim only updating the records after update is running. i want to control the order of execution. i want to execute like when record is inserted my after insert trigger will, run when record is updated my after update trigger will run

```
public class DuplicateTicketHandler {
   

    public void afterinsert(List<Case> newcase){
        List<String> newNaturofIssue = new List<String>();
        List<String> newFacility = new List<String>();
        List<Case>updatedChuld = new List<Case>();
        List<Case> parent = new List<Case>();
        List<Case> Childs = new List<Case>();
        List<Case> childtoupdate= new List<Case>();
        List<Case> childtoupdate2 = new List<Case>();
        Set<Id> newset = new Set<Id>(); 
        Case test;
        for(Case cs : newcase){
            newNaturofIssue.add(cs.Nature_of_issue_Formula__c);
            newFacility.add(cs.Facility_Formula__c);
        }
       
        for(Case cs : [Select Id,Nature_of_issue_Formula__c,Facility_Formula__c from Case where status <> 'closed' and (
            Nature_of_issue_Formula__c IN:newNaturofIssue 
            and
            Facility_Formula__c IN: newFacility) ]){
                newset.add(cs.Id);
                
            }
        
        parent = [Select ID,Status,createdDate from case where Id IN: newset order by createdDate asc Limit 1];
        System.debug(parent + 'parent ===>');
        Childs = [Select ID,Status,createdDate from case where Id IN: newset order by createdDate asc];
        Childs.remove(0);
        System.debug( 'child ===>'+Childs);
        
        if(parent.size()> 0){
            test = parent[0];
            System.debug('test'+test);
        }
        if(Childs.size()>0 ){
            for(Case c : Childs){
                c.ParentId = test.Id;
                updatedChuld.add(c);
                
            }
        }  
        
        System.debug('childupdated===>'+updatedChuld);
        if(updatedChuld.size() > 0){
            update updatedChuld;
        }
        
        System.debug('test===>'+test);
    }
    
    public void afterUpdate(List<Case> OldAcc , List<Case> newAcc, Map<Id, Case> newCase, Map<Id, Case> oldCase){
        List<String> newNaturofIssue = new List<String>();
        List<String> newFacility = new List<String>();
        List<Case> parent = new List<Case>();
        List<Case> Childs = new List<Case>();
        List<Case> childtoupdate= new List<Case>();
        List<Case> childtoupdate2 = new List<Case>();
        Case test ;
        
        for(Case cs : OldAcc){
            newNaturofIssue.add(cs.Nature_of_issue_Formula__c);
            newFacility.add(cs.Facility_Formula__c);
        }
        System.debug('dupliactes'+[Select Id,Nature_of_issue_Formula__c,Facility_Formula__c from Case Where status <> 'Closed'  and (
            Nature_of_issue_Formula__c IN:newNaturofIssue 
            and
            Facility_Formula__c IN: newFacility) ]);
        
        Set<Id> newset = new Set<Id>(); 
        for(Case cs : [Select Id,Nature_of_issue_Formula__c,Facility_Formula__c from Case Where status <> 'Closed'  and (
            Nature_of_issue_Formula__c IN:newNaturofIssue 
            and
            Facility_Formula__c IN: newFacility) ]){
                newset.add(cs.Id);
                
            }
        
        System.debug('newset'+newset);
        
        parent = [Select ID,Status,createdDate from case where Id IN: newset order by createdDate asc Limit 1];
        System.debug(parent + 'parent ===>');
        Childs = [Select ID,Status,createdDate from case where Id IN: newset order by createdDate asc offset 1];
        
        System.debug( 'child ===>'+Childs);
        
        if(parent.size()> 0){
            test = parent[0];
            System.debug('test'+test);
        }
        Case oldparentcase ; 
        Case newparentcase;
        for(Case cs : newAcc){
            oldparentcase = oldCase.get(cs.Id);
            newparentcase =  newCase.get(cs.Id);
            
        }
        if(string.valueOf(oldparentcase.OwnerId).startsWith('00G') && oldparentcase.Status == newparentcase.Status){
            for(Case cstr : childs){
                
                cstr.OwnerId = newparentcase.OwnerId;
                cstr.Status = newparentcase.Status;
                childtoupdate.add(cstr);
                
            }
            
            
        } 
 
        else if(oldparentcase.Status !=  newparentcase.Status){
            for(Case cstr : childs){
                
                cstr.OwnerId = newparentcase.OwnerId;
                cstr.Status = newparentcase.Status;
                childtoupdate2.add(cstr);
                
                
            }
            
        }
        if (childtoupdate.size()>0) {
            update childtoupdate;
        }
        if (childtoupdate2.size()>0) {
            update childtoupdate2;
        }
       
        
        System.debug('childupdate===>'+childtoupdate);  
        System.debug('childupdate2===>'+childtoupdate2);  
        System.debug('oldparentcase===>'+oldparentcase);
        System.debug('oldparentcase====>'+oldparentcase.Nature_of_issue_Formula__c);
        System.debug('oldparentcase====>'+oldparentcase.Facility_Formula__c);
        System.debug('oldparentcase====>'+oldparentcase.Status);
        System.debug('oldparentcase====>'+oldparentcase.OwnerId);
        
        System.debug('newparentcase===>'+newparentcase);
        System.debug('newparentcase====>'+newparentcase.Nature_of_issue_Formula__c);
        System.debug('newparentcase====>'+newparentcase.Facility_Formula__c);
        System.debug('newparentcase====>'+newparentcase.Status);
        System.debug('oldparentcase====>'+newparentcase.OwnerId);
        
        System.debug('childtoupdate===>'+childtoupdate);
        
    }
}
```

handler trigger below

```
trigger DuplicateTicketsTriggerV1 on Case (after insert,after Update) {
    DuplicateTicketHandler dth = new DuplicateTicketHandler();

       if(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter){
        
            dth.afterinsert(Trigger.New);
        
       }
       else {
            if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate){
                 
               dth.afterUpdate(Trigger.Old, Trigger.New, trigger.newMap, trigger.oldMap);
            }
       }
}
```

Comment: Please don't ever write anything in all caps. And things like `PLEASE HELP ME IN URGENT NEED` won't help you get answers more quickly. Probably just the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have more control over what needs to be executed in your trigger (for example, in order to avoid executing the AfterUpdate logic when the AfterInsert has been run already), you can use static class variables to control the execution. For example, say you want to prevent your AfterUpdate logic to be executed if the AfterInsert logic has been executed already, you can modify your class and trigger like this:

```
public class DuplicateTicketHandler {
   

    public static Boolean runAfterUpdate = true;

    public void afterinsert(List<Case> newcase){
        List<String> newNaturofIssue = new List<String>();
        List<String> newFacility = new List<String>();
        List<Case>updatedChuld = new List<Case>();
        List<Case> parent = new List<Case>();
        List<Case> Childs = new List<Case>();
        List<Case> childtoupdate= new List<Case>();
        List<Case> childtoupdate2 = new List<Case>();
        Set<Id> newset = new Set<Id>(); 
        Case test;
        for(Case cs : newcase){
            newNaturofIssue.add(cs.Nature_of_issue_Formula__c);
            newFacility.add(cs.Facility_Formula__c);
        }
       
        for(Case cs : [Select Id,Nature_of_issue_Formula__c,Facility_Formula__c from Case where status <> 'closed' and (
            Nature_of_issue_Formula__c IN:newNaturofIssue 
            and
            Facility_Formula__c IN: newFacility) ]){
                newset.add(cs.Id);
                
            }
        
        parent = [Select ID,Status,createdDate from case where Id IN: newset order by createdDate asc Limit 1];
        System.debug(parent + 'parent ===>');
        Childs = [Select ID,Status,createdDate from case where Id IN: newset order by createdDate asc];
        Childs.remove(0);
        System.debug( 'child ===>'+Childs);
        
        if(parent.size()> 0){
            test = parent[0];
            System.debug('test'+test);
        }
        if(Childs.size()>0 ){
            for(Case c : Childs){
                c.ParentId = test.Id;
                updatedChuld.add(c);
                
            }
        }  
        
        System.debug('childupdated===>'+updatedChuld);
        if(updatedChuld.size() > 0){
            update updatedChuld;
        }
        
        System.debug('test===>'+test);
    }
    
    public void afterUpdate(List<Case> OldAcc , List<Case> newAcc, Map<Id, Case> newCase, Map<Id, Case> oldCase){
        List<String> newNaturofIssue = new List<String>();
        List<String> newFacility = new List<String>();
        List<Case> parent = new List<Case>();
        List<Case> Childs = new List<Case>();
        List<Case> childtoupdate= new List<Case>();
        List<Case> childtoupdate2 = new List<Case>();
        Case test ;
        
        for(Case cs : OldAcc){
            newNaturofIssue.add(cs.Nature_of_issue_Formula__c);
            newFacility.add(cs.Facility_Formula__c);
        }
        System.debug('dupliactes'+[Select Id,Nature_of_issue_Formula__c,Facility_Formula__c from Case Where status <> 'Closed'  and (
            Nature_of_issue_Formula__c IN:newNaturofIssue 
            and
            Facility_Formula__c IN: newFacility) ]);
        
        Set<Id> newset = new Set<Id>(); 
        for(Case cs : [Select Id,Nature_of_issue_Formula__c,Facility_Formula__c from Case Where status <> 'Closed'  and (
            Nature_of_issue_Formula__c IN:newNaturofIssue 
            and
            Facility_Formula__c IN: newFacility) ]){
                newset.add(cs.Id);
                
            }
        
        System.debug('newset'+newset);
        
        parent = [Select ID,Status,createdDate from case where Id IN: newset order by createdDate asc Limit 1];
        System.debug(parent + 'parent ===>');
        Childs = [Select ID,Status,createdDate from case where Id IN: newset order by createdDate asc offset 1];
        
        System.debug( 'child ===>'+Childs);
        
        if(parent.size()> 0){
            test = parent[0];
            System.debug('test'+test);
        }
        Case oldparentcase ; 
        Case newparentcase;
        for(Case cs : newAcc){
            oldparentcase = oldCase.get(cs.Id);
            newparentcase =  newCase.get(cs.Id);
            
        }
        if(string.valueOf(oldparentcase.OwnerId).startsWith('00G') && oldparentcase.Status == newparentcase.Status){
            for(Case cstr : childs){
                
                cstr.OwnerId = newparentcase.OwnerId;
                cstr.Status = newparentcase.Status;
                childtoupdate.add(cstr);
                
            }
            
            
        } 
     
        else if(oldparentcase.Status !=  newparentcase.Status){
            for(Case cstr : childs){
                
                cstr.OwnerId = newparentcase.OwnerId;
                cstr.Status = newparentcase.Status;
                childtoupdate2.add(cstr);
                
                
            }
            
        }
        if (childtoupdate.size()>0) {
            update childtoupdate;
        }
        if (childtoupdate2.size()>0) {
            update childtoupdate2;
        }
       
        
        System.debug('childupdate===>'+childtoupdate);  
        System.debug('childupdate2===>'+childtoupdate2);  
        System.debug('oldparentcase===>'+oldparentcase);
        System.debug('oldparentcase====>'+oldparentcase.Nature_of_issue_Formula__c);
        System.debug('oldparentcase====>'+oldparentcase.Facility_Formula__c);
        System.debug('oldparentcase====>'+oldparentcase.Status);
        System.debug('oldparentcase====>'+oldparentcase.OwnerId);
        
        System.debug('newparentcase===>'+newparentcase);
        System.debug('newparentcase====>'+newparentcase.Nature_of_issue_Formula__c);
```

Trigger:

```
trigger DuplicateTicketsTriggerV1 on Case (after insert,after Update) {
    DuplicateTicketHandler dth = new DuplicateTicketHandler();

       if(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter){
       
            dth.afterinsert(Trigger.New);
            DuplicateTicketHandler.runAfterUpdate = false;
        
       }
       else {
            if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate && DuplicateTicketHandler.runAfterUpdate){
                 
               dth.afterUpdate(Trigger.Old, Trigger.New, trigger.newMap, trigger.oldMap);
            }
       }
}
```